# How to unit test a cachable method

Tags: java, spring, caching

I am using Spring Cache. 
I have a Spring controller and as part of the method responsible for that `GET` request, I have annotated it with `@Cacheable(value = "customer", key = "#accountId")`. In that method, it calls an API and does some business logic and then returns a DTO. With the cache annotation in place, I'm expecting on the first execution of this code will run normally but any subsequent calls later, it'll fetch the result from the cache.. that's correct right?

I'm writing a unit test to verify that the API was called once despite mocking multiple requests being sent to that controller. But the problem is that it keeps on calling the API multiple times and not calling the cache.

Unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
@WebMvcTest(controllers = CustomerController.class, secure = false)
public class CustomerControllerTest {

private static final String ACCOUNT_ID = "1111";

   @MockBean
   private CustomerService customerService;
   @MockBean
   private CustomerPortAPI customerPortAPI;
   @Autowired
   MockMvc mockMvc;

   @Before
   public void setUp(){
      when(customerService.getStatus(any())).thenReturn("test");
      when(customerPortAPI.getAccount(any())).thenReturn(Account.builder().build());
   }
   @Test
public void shouldReturnCustomerDTOt() throws Exception {
  when(customerService.Status(any())).thenReturn("test");
  when(customerPortAPI.getAccount(ACCOUNT_ID)).thenReturn(Account.builder().accountId(ACCOUNT_ID).build());

  mockMvc.perform(get("/customer/{accountId}/status", ACCOUNT_ID)
     .accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
     .andExpect(status().isOk())
     .andExpect(jsonPath("status").value(customer.NOT_REQUIRED.name()));


  mockMvc.perform(get("/customer/{accountId}/status", ACCOUNT_ID)
     .accept(APPLICATION_JSON))
     .andExpect(status().isOk())
     .andExpect(jsonPath("status").value(customer.NOT_REQUIRED.name()));


  verify(customerPorAPI, times(1)).getAccount(ACCOUNT_ID);
```

}}

Controller Method:

```
@Cacheable(value = "statusEligibility", key = "#customerId")
@GetMapping
public CustomerStatusDTO getCustomerStatus(@PathVariable String customerId) {

Customer customer = cusomterPort.getAccount(customerId);
Status status = service.getStatus(customer);

if (status.equals(Cons.REQUIRED)) {
 /.../
} else {
 /.../
}
```

Comment: Springs annotations only work when the objects are created by spring in an application context. When you create your controller with `new` they are not applied. On a side note: you can expect springs `@Cacheable` to work and as its not part of your application you don't / should not test its behaviour as you wouldn't test if e.g. `StringUtils.isEmpty` is working as expected

Comment: Are you sure your test context includes the configuration that enables caching and configures the CacheManager? If it doesn't, then caching is disabled.

Comment: @JBNizet I'm not using any caching config. I'm only using the `@Cachable` annotation in my code along with `EnableCaching`

Comment: Where is EnableCaching placed? Where do you configure the CacheManager bean? And how is your test configured (annotated)? Post al the relevant code.

Comment: @JBNizet I've placed `@EnableCaching` in my main file (it extends `SpringBootServletInitializer`). I haven't configured any CacheManager beans, I'm only using the `@Cachable` annotation on the method in the above post. I've ready somewhere that there is no need to have a cachable manager as caching will still work in method level.

Comment: how is your test configured (annotated)? **Post al the relevant code.**

Comment: @JBNizet done..

Comment: WebMvcTest is annotated with AutoConfigureCache, and AutoConfigureCache 's javadoc says: *Annotation that can be applied to a test class to configure a test CacheManager if none has been defined yet. By default this annotation installs a **NoOpCacheManager**.* (emphasis mine)